# CORS error while fetching data from Azure Function API

Tags: azure, api, azure-functions

I have created an Azure Function API by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/azure-function-cosmos-db-mongo-api?tabs=visualstudiocode tutorial, but whenever I try posting data to it via my react-app using

```
axios.post(url, postData)
```

I get CORS errors, do I need to change anything in index.ts in my API folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running the function app locally, there's an option to configure CORS in local settings file `local.settings.json`

```
{
  "Values": {
  },
  "Host": {
    "CORS": "*"
  }
}
```

For the function app in azure, configure CORS policies in portal.

[image]

Comment: To allow all URLs should I enter * or "*"  in the allowed origins fields? By the way thanks for helping me out.

Comment: You should be using * in the portal.